# using jquery .data() when creating dynamic HTML

Tags: jquery

Most of the HTML in my web app is dynamically generated: I take an object and create a grid row for instance, something like this:

```
var TheHTML = TheHTML + '<div class="HiddenDiv">' + SomeObject.ID + '</div>';
TheHTML = TheHTML + ....
$('#SomeTableContainer').html(TheHTML);
```

That way, when the user clicks on that row, I can access the ID of the object represented on the row using `.find('.HiddenDiv')`

How can I instead  use `.data()` to insert the ID of the object to the row and later retrieve it without reading the ID from the DOM?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't get it, are you really redeclaring the same variable on every line (try +=)? Anyway, `$(TheHTML).data('ID', SomeObject.ID);`

Comment: I'm first generating all the HTML and THEN I'm inserting the final string into the HTML, only once. And yes, doing var TheHTML = TheHTML + is actually the fastest way to do it because browsers became optimized for that. I tested that on jsperf and that's the fastest method.

Comment: @frenchie do it in object way

Comment: @frenchie, I believe he meant you could use `ThenHTML += '<div ....>';` instead of repeating the Variable after the equal sign. Of course that means you should also drop the `var` declaration.

Comment: @frenchie - Are you saying browsers are optimized for you declaring the same variable over and over instead of just adding to it? If so please, pretty please, show me the documentation on that !

Comment: @adeneo, after 20 `<div ... />` has been included, do you really believe using `.data()` on a string with the whole DOM would be a good idea?

Comment: @FernandoCordeiro - Why would data() care how big the object is, it does'nt parse the html or anything, it just attaches arbitrary data to it ?

Comment: @adeneo: sry, I removed the var on line 2; was typo from copy-paste. But yes, the fastest way to build a long string is the way the code is written.

Comment: @frenchie how much faster, do you have a test ?

Comment: And by removing that var you're no longer redeclaring the variable, and I rest my case. As for fastest way, it certainly would be a lot faster to type with "+=" not having to write the same variable name over and over, and the code would be shorter, and as for running time, I'll guess they are so close that you would'nt notice a difference even if you consentenated a million strings.

Comment: @adeneo, my point is 'TheHTML' is not an object. It's a string. I don't even know if `.data()` would work in a string, but if it does, in which `<div>` will it set the ID? Proably the Parent, which I think is not the real `<div>` OP is targeting. I think it would be harder to control or predict the results, so I believe there are better and safer ways to achieve the desired results.

Comment: data() will work on any jQuery object, so "if you wrap it, it will work". If the "theHTML" variable is one row, you can just wrap that and attach data to that variable, and retrieve it later with data() without ever having written anything to the DOM.

Comment: @frenchie, I think adeneo has a good point. `+=` may as well be slower, I don't know, but redeclaring variables on every line (`var`) and repeating this much code is confusing and not worth the risks of someone, editing your code, forget something stupid and break everything. eicto's way is by far the safest.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/mSaRX/ 
i tested $.html(string); vs object model, - less than two times

Comment: this is more correct test i think, because dom should be correctly emptied (to remove all events and other data from parent element) http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/mSaRX/3/ almost same for me - not more than two times difference, IMHO if you not going to generate 1000 elements 100 times in row, you should not worry about optimisation in that place.

Comment: Your test really isn't very accurate with cloning elements and using variables etc. Here's one that's a tad more accurate: http://jsperf.com/inserting-content  and one comparing the earlier mentioned "+=" just for fun : http://jsperf.com/adding-strings

Comment: http://jsperf.com/adding-strings not show difference for me it seems, also your test may be not very accurate  because it does many fancy things, + i can't agree that using clone() and predeclared templates for insert test provide incorrect results, as it is common to optimise $() requests with vars

Answer (score 2, accepted):

custruct DOM in object way:

```
$('#SomeTableContainer').children().remove();

var TheHTML=($('<div>')
   .append($('<div>').html('my subdiv div').data('subid',1))
   .append($('<div>').html('my subdiv div1').data('subid',2))
);
TheHtml.data('id',id);
TheHtml.bind('myevent',function(e){console.log($(this).data('id'));});
$('#SomeTableContainer').append(TheHTML);
```

Comment: he's using `.find()` so I think he wants to add IDs to the INNER Divs.

Comment: That's geat! Your solution is actually way classier than mine. :D

Comment: When creating an element, you can actually do : `$('<div />', {html: 'my subdiv div1'}).data('subid',2);`

Comment: Well anyway, looks like doing it this way is better in code but worse in terms of performance. Thanks for your input, it clarified the deal.

Comment: @frenchie, just take care when you worry so much about performance. A project has to be mantainable. Lotus worried about performance, Microsoft trusted Moore's Law and launched a "bloated" Excel. You know who won. ^^

Comment: @FernandoCordeiro Yes, we know - FSF :)